# Poll environment file for changes

Tags: linux, environment-variables, polling, fuse

I want my FUSE fs to test for a variable to be set in the environment of a process using the fs, for example FUSE_FS_SHOW_DOTFILES for not hiding files/directories. The default behaviour is hiding these.
How can I do this in an efficient way? The pid of the process using the fs is known, so it's possible to parse the environ file in /proc/$pid/environ.
But to do this every command like lookup, getattr, opendir and readdir is very inefficient. You can not look at the modification/change times of this file, since they are always set at current system time (why by the way).
Someone has an idea?

Thanks in advance,

Stef Bon

the Netherlands

Comment: The times are not real because the proc fs like fuse is virtual. There's no real file there. Do you control the setting of variables done by users? You could implement it in your fuse

Comment: Hi Oren Hishon. You write I can implement it in my fuse, and with it you mean the setting of variables done by users. What do you mean? My service cannot control what users set in their environment.

Comment: If you could've controlled the users, they could've instead of setting env, write to a "/proc"  like dir tree in your fuse mount, exposed as configuration interface

Comment: Ok what you suggest is something like getxattr/setxattr on the root or .config file (which is hidden). Is it Oren? In that case yes that's very possible.

Comment: Yep. Either setxattr/getxattr on a specific file or read/write (echo/cat) different config paths to imitate `/proc fs`

Comment: Thanks for the comment Oren. I've been thinking about making use of the set/get xattr of a .config file in the root of my filesystem for various settings like debug level, but did not include the setting hidesettings. It's very possible , and subsettings per network/domain/host/share are possible. Great!

Comment: You should perhaps change the question title to something like "How to pass configuration values to a fuse mount"

Comment: With hinsight yes, but I did bot know that parsing of the enviroonment of the user is use less since changes cant be detected at all. And the sollution you proposed is simpler. Yes. But that happens on the go.

Answer (score 1):

Reading */proc/$pid/environ* wouldn't help since it only reflects the environment at the time the kernel created the process. Any subsequent changes to the environment by the process are not reflected in that file. There is no practical way to do what you're proposing, let alone doing it efficiently. This sounds like a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Huh, I did not know that Kurtis. Where do the variables go then when the user sets them (and exporting)? I do not know any location.

Comment: On UNIX systems the initial set of env vars are put on the stack by the kernel. When the program modifies its env vars it will move them to the heap which the kernel can't access. I've glossed over some details but that's the gist of what happens and why the kernel doesn't have visibility to any env var changes after the process starts running.

Comment: Thanks Kurtis for sharing this. I did not know this. It's very particular and not intuitive.